# Adding Flex SDK 4.5.1 to Eclipse Helios with Flash Builder 4.7 Plug in

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, eclipse-3.6

I am currently in the process of upgrading from Flash Builder 4.6(Trial Version) to Flash Builder 4.7(Trial Version). Prior to installing FB 4.7, my environment set up consisted of all 32 bit specs, and I was able to successfully add the Flex 4.5.1A SDK and build my projects. Now that I have to upgrade to FB 4.7, I have had to switch everything to 64 Bit. When I switched over to 64 bit, I can no longer add Flex SDK 4.5.1 in Eclipse via Window > Preferences > Flash Builder > Installed SDKs. When I set the SDK's folder path, the name is no longer auto populating, and the OK button is disabled. **Why am I unable to add the Flex SDK within this 64 bit version of Eclipse Helios(64 bit)? How would I add the Flex SDK within Eclipse Helios(64 bit)?**

NOTE: When I open the Flash Builder application, the 4.5.1A Flex SDK appears under Installed SDKS.

Current Environment Set Up (Not Working):

- Windows 8 64 bit
- Eclipse Helios 64 bit
- JAVA SDK 6.11 64 Bit
- Flash Builder 4.7 64 bit
- Flex SDK 4.5.1A (located in Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\sdks)

Previous Environment Set Up (Working, until trial expired):

- Windows 8 64 bit
- Eclipse Helios 32 bit
- JAVA SDK 6.11 32 Bit
- Flash Builder 4.6 32 bit
- Flex SDK 4.5.1A (located in Program Files(x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks)

-Since, I have a 64 bit machine, I am only able to install FB 4.7 64 bit, according to Adobe's website

I've been researching for the past few days, and no luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing the Flash Builder 4.7 plug-in with Helios but wasn't able to get it to work.  It appears to need Indigo or later.